# Let $X,Y$ independent random variables such that $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, and $Y\sim\text{Poisson}(\mu)$.

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ independent random variables such that $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, and
$Y\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\mu)$. Let $Z=X+Y$ find the probability function of $X$ and $Z$.

Using the idea of the user @Surb. i have:

$\mathbb P\{X=k,Z=m\}=\mathbb P\{X=k, X+Y=m\}=\mathbb P\{X=k, Y=m-k\}=P(X=k)P(Y=m-k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^{m-k}}{(m-k)!}=e^{-(\lambda +\mu)}\frac{\lambda^k \mu^{m-k}}{k!(m-k)!}$

Then the probability function of $Z$ is

$p(m,k)=\begin{cases}
e^{-(\lambda +\mu)}\frac{\lambda^k \mu^{m-k}}{k!(m-k)!} && \text{if}& m\leq k \\
0 && \text{if} & m>k
\end{cases}$

Comment: You have this only when $m\geq k$. When $m<k$ then $\mathbb P\{X=k, Z=m\}=0$

Comment: Thanks @Surb i put the probability function in my question

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Thanks for all, very glad for you help @Surb have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $m,k\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $m\geq k$. Then

$$\mathbb P\{X=k,Z=m\}=\mathbb P\{X=k, X+Y=m\}=\mathbb P\{X=k, Y=m-k\}=...$$

I let you conclude when $m<k$.

Comment: Then  $P(Z=z)=e^(\lambda +\mu)\frac{(\lambda +\mu)^z}{z!}$

Comment: I edited my answer. @Bvss12

Comment: Thanks, then i need know when $m<k$ and with that i can find the probability function. no?

Comment: Yes exactly. But don't look to far for the case $m<k$ because it's really obvious.@Bvss12

Comment: Okay, i go to try solve and comment here for any question. Thanks for all!

Comment: I edit my question, i'm little confused in that part. Can you see that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the approach using $P(Z=n)=\sum_{k=0}^n P(X=k)P(Y=n-k)$ has already been covered, I'll discuss a different one that requires less combinatorics. Define $$G_X(t):=\mathbb{E}t^X=\sum_{k\ge 0}e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}=e^{\lambda (t-1)}.$$This power series has $t^k$ coefficient $P(X=k)$, so is called a probability generating function. Clearly, $G_Z=\mathbb{E}t^X t^Y=G_X G_Y=e^{(\lambda+\mu)(t-1)}$, i.e. $Z$ is Poisson-distributed with parameter $\lambda+\mu$.